# linq getting datarow and iterating each field based on Column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Datatable where I am trying to check if a certain row in the datatable is all null or empty. I have a linq statement where I get the row by index and I am able to see the row values, but I dont know how to check which column the values belong to and if the value is null or empty. How do I find the Column Names and the Column Values when I am in the foreach and in this case have the datarow called "row"

```
int rowIndex = 9; 
DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where((row, index) => index == rowIndex).ToList()
.ForEach(row => {
               //Trying to iterate thru each column in the row
               //Check the column Name that currently on
               //get the value
            });
```

Comment: Not really sure about your question, do you know the column name before hand, do you know the value to compare ? how would you manage comparing different types ?

Comment: yes I know the column names before hand all I am really trying to check if the whole datarow is either null or 0 except for one field which I know

Answer (score 2):

```
var ColumnToIngorn = DataTable.Columns["XXX"].Ordinal;
var ArrItem = DataTable.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray.Where((item, indexColumn) => indexColumn != ColumnToIngorn);

foreach (var item in ArrItem)
    ...
```

or:

```
var ArrItem = DataTable.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray.Select((item, indexColumn) => new { index = indexColumn, value = item });

foreach (var item in ArrItem)
{
    if (item.index == 5) //Check index column
        ...
    if (DataTable.Columns[item.index].ColumnName == "XXX") //check name column
        ...
}
```